# Java ArchUnit: detect annotation on getMethodCallsFromSelf mehods

Tags: java, archunit

I annotated some methods with a custom annotation: "ExistForTesting"

```
@Documented
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, METHOD})
@Retention(SOURCE)
public @interface ExistForTesting {
    String why() default "";
}
```

I'd like to write a (Junit5 + ArchUnit) unit test that ensures ExistForTesting annotated methods are used from unit tests only. So, I wrote the given test:

```
ArchCondition<JavaClass> NOT_CALL_TEST_METHODS =
    new ArchCondition<JavaClass>("not call methods annotated with ExistForTesting") {
        @Override
        public void check(@NotNull JavaClass item, ConditionEvents events) {
            item.getMethodCallsFromSelf().stream().filter(method -> method.getTarget().isAnnotatedWith(ExistForTesting.class))
                .forEach(method -> {
                    String message = String.format(
                        "Method %s is annotated with ExistForTesting",
                        method.getTarget().getFullName());
                    events.add(SimpleConditionEvent.violated(method, message));
                });
        }
    };

@Test
public void shouldNotUseTestMethods() {
    classes().that()
        .haveSimpleNameNotEndingWith("Test")
        .should(NOT_CALL_TEST_METHODS)
        .check(appClasses);
}
```

Problem: my annotation is not detected.
The debugger finds methods calls, but `method.getTarget().isAnnotatedWith(ExistForTesting.class))` always returns `false`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, my annotation retention was set to SOURCE instead of CLASS.
Fixed.

Comment: you can accept your own answer to make it visible already in the overview, that your question is solved.